# The entity is not updated on entity listener @PostPersist (Spring data jpa)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have next ER diagram
[image]
I want to update *PlayerStat* entity every time I save *Score* entity. So I tried to use `@PostPersist` annotation. And when I save *Score* entity, function with that annotation called, but changes, that I do in this function do not persist. My implementation is below. All entity classes have lombok annotations for contructors.
**Player**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "custom-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Getter
@NonNull
private Date createdAt;

@Column(unique = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NonNull
private String nickname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "winner")
@Getter
@NonNull
private Set<Game> gamesWon;

@Getter
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
@JoinColumn
private PlayerStat stat;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
@Getter
@NonNull
private Set<Score> scores;

public Player(String nickname, Date createdAt) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    stat = new PlayerStat(0, 0, 0, this);
}
```

**Game**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "custom-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@Getter
@NonNull
@Column(updatable = false)
private Integer durationMinutes;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Getter
@NonNull
private Date dateStarted;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn
@Getter
@NonNull
private Player winner;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
@Getter
private Set<Score> scores;

@PostPersist
private void update(){
    System.out.println("On game post persist");
    winner.getStat().incrementTotalWins();
}
```

**PlayerStat**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "custom-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@Getter
@Setter
@NonNull
private Integer totalScore;

@Getter
@NonNull
private Integer totalWins;

@Getter
@NonNull
private Integer totalGames;

@Getter
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "stat", optional = false)
@NonNull
private Player player;

public void incrementTotalWins() {
    totalWins++;
}

public void incrementTotalGames() {
    totalGames++;
}
```

**Score**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "custom-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;


@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "game_id")
@Getter
@NonNull
private Game game;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn
@Getter
@NonNull
private Player player;

@Getter
@NonNull
private Integer score;



@PostPersist
void updatePlayerStat(){
    System.out.println("On score post persist");
    player.getStat().incrementTotalGames();
    player.getStat().setTotalScore(player.getStat().getTotalScore() + score);
    System.out.println(player);
}
```

So, I try to save single *Player*, *Game* with that player, and *Score* with that game and player. Both function, annotated with `@PostPersist` called. Thenm in another request I read this player. Changes, did in *Game* function applied, but changes did in *Score* functions not. But if I do separate request like this (it has nothing to do with Entity listener)

```
score.getPlayer().getStat().incrementTotalGames();
score.getPlayer().getStat().incrementTotalWins();
score.getPlayer().getStat().setTotalScore(100);
scoreRepository.save(score);
```

All changes will be applied.
I also tried to use separate EntityListener class and get in that class repository, save modified object, but this doesn't work too. And I tried to add `CascadeType.ALL` in every relations, still no changes. So what I should do to autoupdate PlayerStat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use  `@PostPersist` the information will update after persistance so you'll not have the information in the database so you should do this incrementation in the  service layer before save your result in the dataBase, you can also try :

1- `@PrePersist` because PrePersist Executed **before** the entity manager persist operation is actually executed or **cascaded**. This call is synchronous with the persist operation.

2-`@PreUpdate` because  PreUpdate Executed **before** the database **UPDATE** operation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that what you want is **@PrePersist**?

And you do want to add **cascade** to player in Game, and

Comment: Yeah, with **@PrePersist** seems work fine. Thank you. Now it works without additional cascasde.

Answer (score 0):

`@PostPersist` -and other callback methods- has limitations , from which, It can't update entity state

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (in WildFly) you have to flush the save statements manually, otherwise the changes are lost. See also the notes in the JPA spec (JPA 2.2 section 3.5.3). The exact point when the post persist method is called in relation with transaction demarcation does not seem very precisely defined.